# Низкая скорость чтения записей, следующих подряд (читаемых в порядке прошлого вывода)

Tags: mysql, база-данных, postgresql

Здравствуйте!
Вопрос относительно скорости чтения из таблицы РСУБД.
Зачастую требуется прочитать большую серию записей, следующих подряд. То есть прочитать в том же порядке, как осуществлялся в свое время вывод записей в таблицу.
При этом в нашем случае записи внутри таблицы никогда не удаляются. Например, записываем данные моделирования поведения сложного физического объекта, и мы не можем что-либо изменить в прошлом, не пересчитав последующий процесс (причинно-следственные связи).
Задача в том, чтобы обеспечить скорость, близкую к скорости чтения последовательного бинарного файла.
Если таблица хранится в отдельном файле (как, например, MyISAM), то можно гарантировать, что данные следует прочитать в этом самом файле таблицы подряд: фактически естественно это сделать единственной командой чтения из файла (как при "ручной" работе с бинарным файлом).
Тем не менее, реляционная БД всё равно роется в индексах, что радикально замедляет обмен.

Comment: Не маловажную роль играет то, когда вы создаете индекс. Перед вставкой данных или после.

Answer (score 2):

> Зачастую требуется прочитать большую серию записей, следующих подряд. То есть прочитать в том же порядке, как осуществлялся в свое время вывод записей в таблицу.

Нет такого порядка. Есть либо порядок, определяемый предложением ORDER BY, либо порядок не определён.

Обычно если сортировка не указана, записи отдаются в порядке сортировки по кластерному либо первичному индексу - но это верно только для получения записей из одной таблицы, и только при отборе с использованием этого индекса.

Если Вы желаете получить чтение бинарного файла - отказывайтесь от СУБД и используйте файловое хранение данных. А заодно думайте, как обеспечить нефрагментированность такого файла.

Comment: Это все понятно. Сформулирую вопрос несколько иначе. Пусть в таблице никогда не удаляются внутренние записи. Т.е. либо удаляются последние записи, либо вся таблица. Пусть для простоты у нас autoincrement индекс. И пусть записи всегда выводятся большими сериями (например, по 100 000 записей). И пусть используется таблица MyISAM (таблица хранится в собственном файле). При попытке чтения 100 000 записей в порядке первичного индекса гарантируется, что вся информация может быть прочитана за 1 команду чтения из файла. При этом БД впустую роется в индексах, радикально замедляясь.

Comment: P.S.
На самом деле требование запрета на удаление данных внутри таблицы - достаточно мягкое для многих приложений с большими данными. При этом и вывод серии записей и чтение в этом же порядке (т.е. пл первичному ключу) может производиться со скоростью обмена с двоичным файлом. Более того, тяжелые запросы именно можно свести к такому чтению за счет организации данных. А множество остальных различных запросов характеризуется малой величиной выборки, и скорость работы реляционной базы будет достаточна. Т.е. требуется движок наподобие упрощенного MyISAM, но такого не нашел...

Comment: Пояснения требуют конкретизации. Если речь идёт о простейшем запросе типа SELECT * FROM table, то индекс использоваться не должен - по причине отсутствия условия отбора. А если условие имеется, то можно попробовать перевести INDEX SCAN в FULLSCAN использованием IGNORE INDEX.

Comment: Заодно помните, что сервер не сам лезет в файл, а отправляет требование файловому реквестору. А что и как будет делать дисковая подсистема - фиг знает. Насколько мне известно, ни одна ОС так и не повторила Новелловского лифта, ограничиваясь кэшированием и аппаратным предчтением.

Comment: Спасибо за участие в обсуждении вопроса.
Понятно, что можно и нужно заниматься тюнингом запросов и настройками сервера для ускорения операций ввода/вывода в таблицы РСУБД.
В справке MySQL
http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Tips.html
говорится:
«Если вам действительно нужна высокая скорость, вы должны взглянуть на интерфейсы нижнего уровня....Можно было бы избавиться от вышеуказанных проблем введением низко-уровневых команд MyISAM в сервере MySQL (это был бы один из простых путей получить большую производительность, если необходимо)...»

К сожалению, пишется в сослагательном наклонении...

Comment: Эммм... Вы на версию мануала посмотрели, прежде чем цитировать?

Comment: Вы прочитайте цитируемый абзац полностью по ссылке. В комментарий абзац полностью не помещается.

Разве здесь что-то изменилось??
Имхо, эти возможности и ныне не входят в перечень основной функциональности. Буду рад, если просветите.

Comment: Вот если бы Вы дали ссылку на оригинальную документацию ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-optimization-tips.html ), а не на сочинение по мотивам документации, устаревшей на два потопа - слова бы не сказал... кстати, сравните ради любопытства и прикиньте причины, по которым этот абзац со времён четвёртой версии так похудел и изменился...

Comment: Мы как раз и начали заниматься тестами с целью увеличить скорость при последовательном [большими сериями записей] чтении/записи таблиц. Если ввязываться в низкоуровневый обмен, возможны варианты при выходе новых версий СУБД.
Эта тема большая на самом деле, не для формата настоящих комментариев. Потребуется оптимизация операций типа конкатенации индексов в важных частных случаях и многое другое.

Comment: Увеличить - за счёт каких именно мероприятий? да и не ввяжетесь вы в "низкоуровневый обмен" - потому как сервер и сам не знает, куда будут падать записываемые им на диск байты. А пытаться создать новый движок, работающий на своей собственной файловой системе (или работающий с файловой системой напрямую, минуя файловые сервисы)... это надо быть слишком энтузиастом, причём каждому из команды, без исключений.

Comment: Да на самом деле обсуждаемые вопросы - отнюдь не суперсложные с т.зр. большого проекта. Например, применительно к Зеленограду: моделирование сверхчистых помещений с целью выхода на решение обратных задач. Хотя могут быть задачи и посложнее. Не боги горшки обжигают. Всего доброго! Удачи!